# Wrong result while using _addcarry_u64 on MSVC 2017

Tags: visual-c++, c++17

I am trying to write a simple library to work with long integers. Using of special optimization based on intrinsic method _addcarry_u64 of 64-bit compiler get an unexpected result in the following code if used optimization. Debug version working as expected.

```
inline uint64_t addc(const uint64_t& value1, const uint64_t& value2, uint64_t& carry) noexcept
{
    uint64_t result;
    carry = _addcarry_u64(static_cast<uint8_t>(carry), value1, value2, &result);

    return result;
}

template<typename native_t = uintmax_t>
class long_t
{
public:
    static_assert(std::is_unsigned_v<native_t>, "unsigned long integer native type must be unsigned");

    using native_array_t = std::array<native_t, 2>;

    long_t() noexcept;
    constexpr long_t(const long_t& that) noexcept = default;
    constexpr long_t(long_t&& that) noexcept = default;
    constexpr long_t(native_array_t digits) noexcept;
    constexpr long_t(const native_t& value) noexcept;
    template<typename type_t, std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned_v<type_t>, int> = 0>
    constexpr long_t(type_t value) noexcept;
    template<typename type_t, std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed_v<type_t>, int> = 0>
    constexpr long_t(type_t value) noexcept;

    constexpr bool operator==(const long_t& that) const noexcept;
    constexpr long_t& operator+=(const long_t& that) noexcept;
    constexpr long_t operator+(const long_t& that) const noexcept;

    native_array_t digits;
};
template<typename native_t>
inline long_t<native_t>::long_t() noexcept
{
}

template<typename native_t>
inline constexpr long_t<native_t>::long_t(native_array_t digits) noexcept
: digits(digits)
{
}

template<typename native_t>
inline constexpr long_t<native_t>::long_t(const native_t& value) noexcept
: long_t({ value, 0})
{
}

template<typename native_t>
template<typename type_t, std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned_v<type_t>, int>>
inline constexpr long_t<native_t>::long_t(type_t value) noexcept
: long_t({ native_t(value), 0 })
{
}

template<typename native_t>
template<typename type_t, std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed_v<type_t>, int>>
inline constexpr long_t<native_t>::long_t(type_t value) noexcept
: long_t({ static_cast<native_t>(value), (value >= 0 ? 0 : native_t(~0)) })
{
}

template<typename native_t>
inline constexpr bool long_t<native_t>::operator==(const long_t& that) const noexcept
{
    if (digits[1] != that.digits[1])
        return false;

    if (digits[0] != that.digits[0])
        return false;


    return true;
}

template<typename native_t>
inline constexpr long_t<native_t>& long_t<native_t>::operator+=(const long_t& that) noexcept
{
    native_t carry = 0;

    digits[0] = addc(digits[0], that.digits[0], carry);
    digits[1] = addc(digits[1], that.digits[1], carry);

    return *this;
}

template<typename native_t>
inline constexpr long_t<native_t> long_t<native_t>::operator+(const long_t& that) const noexcept
{
    return long_t(*this) += that;
}

int main()
{
    const bool result = long_t<uintmax_t>(0) + -1 == -1;

    std::cout << "result:" << result;

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
result:0
```

Replacing of optimized addc version caused to predictable result:

```
template<typename type_t, std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned_v<type_t>, int>>
inline constexpr type_t addc(const type_t& value1, const type_t& value2, type_t& carry) noexcept
{
    const type_t tmp = value2 + carry;
    const type_t result = value1 + tmp;
    carry = (tmp < value2) || (result < value1);

    return result;
}
```

Output is:

```
result:1
```

The problem appears on Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.23 on 64-bit C++ compiler in full optimization mode.

Comment: Works for me in VS2019. Why, congratulations on finding a compiler bug. Possibly you need to look at disassembly to have more solid proof that it is a compiler bug. Also I don't recommend references, take integers by value, and return a pair or struct with carry flag and the result, it might fix the issue.

Comment: Yes, it works on VS2019 and GCC compilers. I have checked disassemble output and it looks buggy for me but I have no strong skills in assembler to approve this. Carry flag doesn't correctly set before adding of array second members.  The problem is that I'am still staying on VS 2017 at this moment.

Comment: Generally, you have to either upgrade or workaround youself, they will not fix bugs in old product. Try to avoid references, or if this does not help, substitute intrinsic directly into call site instead of `addc` function